# Best practice solution for storing "unsigned long long" number in Realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm, long-integer

I have to store large numbers in `Realm` storage like `14000822124935161134`. Currently I store them by changing the type of them to `string` as follows and then save it:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *itemInsert = [item mutableCopy];

    if([item valueForKey:@"timestamp"]) {
        unsigned long long timestamp = [[item valueForKey:@"timestamp"] unsignedLongLongValue];
        [itemInsert setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llu", timestamp] forKey:@"timestamp"];
    }

    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [RMember createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:itemInsert];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

And the `timestamp` property of my `RLMObject` is defined as follows :

```
@interface RMember : RLMObject
...
@property (nullable) NSString *timestamp;
...
@end
```

Is there any suitable type rather than `string` for this type of data in `Realm` or any better solution?

Comment: Silly idea, but if it's a timestamp, couldn't you just store a NSDate?

Comment: It has a bit different structure and converting to NSDate is not recommended. Thanks any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm supports `long long`; it just doesn't support the `unsigned` variant.

You could simply save the value as `long long` and provide a getter accessor that explicitly casts it back to `unsigned long long` when retrieved from the database.

```
@interface RMember : RLMObject
@property long long timestamp;
@end

unsigned long long timestamp = [[item valueForKey:@"timestamp"] unsignedLongLongValue];

RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
RMember *myObject = ...;
[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    myObject.timestamp = (long long)timestamp;
}];

unsigned long long savedTimestamp = (unsigned long long)myObject.timestamp;
NSLog(@"Saved timestamp is %llu", savedTimestamp);
```

Tested on my iPad Air and it seemed to be working as expected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately It's not correct. The `savedTimestamp` is something with different value from the first one. The real number is `13951113131432254825`, the saved number in database is `-4495630942277296791`, and the final displayed number is `107202386029632`

Comment: Hmm, that's curious. I tested it myself and as far as I could tell, it was working as I was expecting. I attached a screenshot of what I tried. Yep! It would make sense that it's represented as a negative number in the database itself because it's saved as a `signed long long`. So while the binary data is exactly the same, it's being interpreted differently. As long as you're making sure you're typecasting the data properly, it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks TiM. Yes, That was without anyproblem for the second test I've had.