# max value of string in realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I intended to get the max value of `string` type in `Realm` by `maxOfProperty` method as follows:

```
[[MyRealmObject allObjects] maxOfProperty:propertyName]
```

However, I encountered the following error:

> maxProperty is not supported for string property

Considering I can't change the type of property, what should I do now?

Comment: What are you expecting this to return? I can't think what would be considered the `max` of a string...

Comment: very big numbers represented in string

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a string property? I'd strongly suggest changing the type of the property to one of the numeric types that Realm supports, which will allow the code you've shared to work as you expect.

Comment: unsigned long long is not supported by Realm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763199/best-practice-solution-for-storing-unsigned-long-long-number-in-realm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use this solution

```
[[[[MyRealmObject allObjects] sortedResultsUsingKeyPath:propertyName ascending:NO] firstObject] objectForKeyedSubscript:propertyName];
```

Answer (score 0):

`maxOfProperty` is only supported for `int`, `float`, `double`, and `NSDate` types, see more in [docs](https://realm.io/docs/objc/2.4.2/api/Classes/RLMResults.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMResults(im)maxOfProperty:).

There is no any builtin solution for your case, I'd suggest you to store the maximum value as a separate object and update it everytime you modify the database or just query all objects and find the maximum value by comparing it manually.

Comment: How about this way: '[[[[aClass allObjects] sortedResultsUsingKeyPath:propertyName ascending:NO] firstObject] objectForKeyedSubscript:propertyName]'